# Controlar troca de posição de uma recyclerview através de uma progressBar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-recyclerview

Estou tentando fazer uma rotina, onde eu controlo a minha passagem de item da minha `recyclerView` por uma `progressBar`, ou seja, toda vez que eu mudar de item, essa mudança tem que refletir na progress. O problema, é que só estou conseguindo pegar a `position` quando eu clico, não consigo pegar pela passagem de item.
Segue código abaixo:
Código Adapter:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
public interface ProgressBar{void Progress(int questao);}
public void ProgressBarListener(ProgressBar progressBar){this.progressBar=progressBar;}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Tentativa de pegar a mudança de questão da recycler
        progressBar.Progress(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

Código Activity:

```
 //Tentativa de pegar a mudança de questão da recycler
    adapter.ProgressBarListener(new Question2Adapter.ProgressBar() {
        @Override
        public void Progress(int questao) {
            textBar.setText(questao+1+"");
            Log.w("postion",questao+1+"");
            progressBar.setProgress(questao+1);
        }
    });
```

Imagem da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou desta forma: `int adapterPosition = MyViewHolder .this.getAdapterPosition()` ?

Comment: Tentei agr, dentro do construtor do MyViewHolder retornou -1 e no clique, retorna a position, mas apenas no clique.